# How to get the same xml element value of multiple files in a directories and its subdirectories using java?

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

- I have a Directory with its subdirectories and it has a number of xml files.
- The XML files can be there with same name in different directories.
- But it has an xml Element as  and it is very unique for all the files even though it holds the same xml file name.
- Now I want to read and store all the xml element  in to a LIST
  with its xml file name and directory path.
- It has a common root directory,for instance it can have the below root path 
  `D:\test\28-4-2016\BPG\8451835_1\ItemFile\1461819815710_19\ftp\content-providers\bpl-e\data\incoming`

Below I have provided my code snippet.

```
File fXmlFile = new File(path_received);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory  = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList2=doc.getElementsByTagName("CE:DOI");
if(nList2.getLength()>=1)
{
     for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nList2.getLength(); temp2++) {
         Node nNode4 = nList2.item(temp2);

         if (nNode4.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
         {
            Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode4;
            issn_value[temp2]=eElement1.getTextContent();
       } 
               }
  }
```

-----------Code ends--------------
Now I am getting the single data only.
can any one help me to achieve this as per my above requirement.

Thanks in Advance

------------------Stack trace of present error : --------------------------

java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\project_new\ttest\CBS_v47i4_e.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at ttest.FileDemo.main(FileDemo.java:46)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear to me what you are you trying to achieve. But it seems to me that you want to scan a folder for .xml files and get a particular element from all these .xml files and store it into the list.

Below is a sample program that scans a folder for .xml files and stores all
"Element : path" strings into a list. You can use a StringTokenizer to separate them. Also using StringTokenizer you can separate the file name from the file path.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class FileDemo {

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = null;
        try {
            // create new file
            String root = "C:\\temp";
            f = new File(root);

            //shall accept all files in directories and subdirectories
            List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(f, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);

            ArrayList<String> issn_valueLst = new ArrayList<>();

            for (File fXmlFile : files) {
                // prints filename and directory name
                if(accept(fXmlFile.getName(), ".xml")){
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory  = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList nList2=doc.getElementsByTagName("CE:DOI");
                if(nList2.getLength()>=1)
                {
                     for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nList2.getLength(); temp2++) {
                         Node nNode4 = nList2.item(temp2);

                         if (nNode4.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                         {
                            Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode4;
                            issn_valueLst.add(eElement1.getTextContent()+"-"+fXmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
                       } 
                               }
                  }
                }
            }
           // }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if any error occurs
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static boolean accept( String name, String str) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(str.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ,Thank you for your valuable reply,but it Throws file not found exception after changing the root path to :       f = new File("D:\\test\\28-4-2016\\xmls");,kindly help,provided stack trace.\

Comment: It takes the wrong path as : java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\project_new\ttest\CBS_v47i4_e.xml (The system cannot find the file specified),kindly help

Comment: Hi, I have provided an edited code above. You just need to put the file location for variable f. And it shall automatically scan the folder for .xml files. please vote up if this is helpful. :)

Comment: @ Mateen: Thank you,will do it.But Still i am getting the same error as java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\project_new\ttest\CBS_v47i4_e.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Source file location it searches is wrong.and i have provided the path already.kindly help

Comment: hey, missed out the fact the filter gives only .xml files. I have appended the root directory and now it is fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: Happy to help. Enjoy coding :)

Comment: pls help.one more request.It is not reading the xml files which is in subdirectories.kindly help

Comment: here is a [link] [http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-get-all-files-in-a-directory-including-subdirectories-using-commons-io.html] that uses apache Files.Listfiles. However it accepts a IOFilter to scan directories and subdirectories. We have used a FileNameFilter for the above code. You can try using some of this.

Comment: @ : Mateen :Sorry to disturb.Its not reading the xml files in side the subdirectories.

Comment: @ Mateen : please help me to implement it sir.I am very new to this process.Kndlly help me sir.

Comment: Here you go. Edited the answer with new code. Though i have got rid of the FileNameFilter this code does essentially what you are looking for i hope! . Have a nice day